# Lambda service quotas with boto3/aws cli return with no results

Tags: boto3, aws-cli

I'm trying to get the latest Lambda Concurrent Executions quota using Boto3 or CLI and both return empty. We have increased the quota a few times to now 2500 however, in the console, it shows "Applied quota Value" is "Not Available".  Any ideas on how to get current value?

```
$> aws service-quotas list-service-quotas --service-code "lambda"
{
    "Quotas": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get AWS Lambda concurrent executions limit using Lambda [GetAccountSettings API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_GetAccountSettings.html) via [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-account-settings.html):

```sh
aws lambda get-account-settings
```

Output:

```json
{
    "AccountLimit": {
        "TotalCodeSize": 80530636800,
        "CodeSizeUnzipped": 262144000,
        "CodeSizeZipped": 52428800,
        "ConcurrentExecutions": 1000,
        "UnreservedConcurrentExecutions": 1000
    },
    "AccountUsage": {
        "TotalCodeSize": 10,
        "FunctionCount": 1
    }
}
```

If you just need the concurrent executions limit, you can extract it using `--query`:

```sh
aws lambda get-account-settings --output text --query "AccountLimit.ConcurrentExecutions"
```

Output:

```
1000
```